# Tomcat: Could not be found or loaded

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

When I try to run my project in

```
tomcat Error: main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat $ 1 Could not be found or loaded
```

Running the Tomcat server without my project it seems to be alright. 
But adding my project to it I get the issue:

I have set the path of tomcat to the right JRE but I keep getting the error.

What else should I check to solve the problem ?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SMSCloudService</display-name>

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Controller class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/hello" , "/"})
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Comment: there's this weird `$ 1` in the error message. How exactly are you starting tomcat and what do you mean by "with and without" your application. Have you deployed applications to tomcat before or is this your first one?

Comment: Yes, this is my first application I deploy to tomcat. My project ist set under "Run As.." to tomcat. If I click on the run button the console shows me that weird message. The problem only appears, if my project is deployed to the tomcat. if I delete it and the tomcat contains no projects the weird message is not shown. By the way, the message is displayed in german I tried to translate it. The original looks as follows: Fehler: Hauptklasse org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$1 konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

Comment: this is eclipse, right?

Comment: yes, this is eclipse. It is STS if it matters

Comment: Maybe you are trying to mix an embedded Tomcat and an external one?

Answer (score 0):

please try the following,

- in the "servers" view, right click on your tomcat server and choose "add and remove...", then add your application.
- Now start the tomcat through this view, e.g. right click the server and select "start".

This should start tomcat including all deployed webapps. You can browse to your app typically via `http://localhost:8080/your-context`

Comment: Through the "add and remove" view I have deleted the project from the server and added it again. I do not see any option there to start the server. Clicking on the finish button does not start tomcat either. I have started it by running the project ... The same problem as before

Comment: there's a start option in the right-click popup menu of the server. Also there's a `>` button at the top of the servers view.